# Django OrderBy using ManyToMany table

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have the models:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=200)                        

class Car(models.Model):
    categorys = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
```

Constantly new cars are added.

I'd like to get the last 20 categories that had a car of her type added.

I got to set up a filter, but when I got to order by I could not get it anymore.

Since I can not close any logic I will not put what I have tried here.

**Updating**

I add 3 cars:

- Car 1 have 2 categories (cat1 and cat2)
- Car 2 have 3 categories (cat2, cat20, cat3)
- Car 3 have 2 categories (cat4, cat1, cat90)

I need to get:
cat1, cat2, cat3, cat4, cat20, cat90 and others...

Answer (score 0):

So you have this models:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=200)                        

class Car(models.Model):
    categorys = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
```

According to this phrase:

> I'd like to get the last 20 categories that had a car of her type
>   added.

at first we have to find the car:

```
car = Car.objects.get("""your parameters""")
```

Then we have to find categories:

```
category = car.category_set.all()[:20]
```

Try this

**UPD**
When you get all `Cars` and `Category` that you need, you can get to any of category object.

```
categories = Cars.objects.filter("""your filter""").select_related('categorys')
for category in categories.categorys_set():
  print(category.description)
```

Comment: In your example `Restaurant` have a `pizzas` property, in my case, `Category` do not have a `cars` property. Looking at the documentation I could not find an example of Topping >> Pizza. Just Pizza> Topping

Comment: I just change my answer, tcheck it

Comment: Not that ... I improved my question. Sorry for the mess.

Comment: This will give me the cars, I want the categories ... (cat1, cat2, cat3 ...)

Comment: Yes, this is what I need, only at the time of execution that gave this error: `AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'categorys_set' `

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130337/discussion-between-zagorodniy-olexiy-and-ricardo).

Answer (score 0):

I use **extra()** function to solve the problem.
See code blow:

```html
class School(models.Model):
  ...
  tag = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)

  def tags(self):
    meta = self.tag.through._meta
    db_table = meta.db_table
    primary_key = meta.pk.name
    order_by = [db_table + '.' + primary_key]
    return list(self.tag.extra(order_by=order_by).values_list('name', flat=True))
```

By adding **order by** to sql statement to make results order by  pk of **through** (if not specified django will create a table for you automaticly) table.
Hope this will be helpful.